# python checking if coordinates already exist in list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

This work is for an assignment. I am working with a 2d array and so far I have found a path that I want to take through the array. There are other paths in the array and I want to be able to go through them as well but I cannot reuse any paths. My array looks like:

```
0,2,4,1,6,0,0
2,0,0,0,5,0,0
4,0,0,0,5,5,0
1,0,0,0,1,1,0
6,5,0,1,0,5,5
0,0,5,1,5,0,0
0,0,0,0,5,0,0
```

My code for finding nearby neighbours is:

```
def check_neighbours(Alist, node):
        nodes = []
        for i in range(0,2):
                for j in range(0,2):
                        x = node[0]+i
                        y = node[1]+j
                        if x>=0 and y>=0 and (i!=0 or j!=0) and Alist[x][y]>0:
                                nodes.append([x, y])
```

I am appending each visited coordinate x,y to a list which builds up the full path taken. Here is an example of the output:

```
inside pathing function
path taken is ['[0, 1]', '[0, 2]', '[0, 3]', '[0, 4]', '[1, 4]', '[2, 4]', '[2, 5]', '[3, 5]', '[4, 5]', '[4, 6]']
```

Because of the way I am searching for neighbours (having x and y separated) I cannot think of a way of testing whether or not the current coordinate that is built up is already located inside of the list. I think that the code would fit in between the following two lines:

```
if x>=0 and y>=0 and (i!=0 or j!=0) and Alist[x][y]>0:
                                    nodes.append([x, y])
```

Comment: According to the way the condition is constructed (namely, `i!=0 or j!=0`) variable `nodes` will never contain the same coordinates. Of course as long as we're talking about `nodes` variable within `check_neighbours` scope.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
nodes = []
nodes.append([1,1])
nodes.append([2,2])
nodes.append([3,3])

[1,1] in nodes
# True

[1,3] in nodes
# False
```

I'm not really clear on your question, so this may be off.

That being said, since, in order to be added to the `nodes` list, it has to be either one column to the right, one below, or both, of the previous node.  And since you're only considering nodes to the right and below (`range(0,2)`), you can never get duplicates in your list.